# How to require one of two fields to be filled out?

Tags: 7, entities

Let's say i have two fields in a content type. An integer field and a text field (two options with select list widget) and i want the user to fill out one of the two.
Can someone help me achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.