# Can webform conditionals require filling one of two fields?

Tags: webforms

The snippet below is one of the ways I attempted to require that the user fill out at least one of phone no. and/or email using webform conditionals. This one came closest to working. The logic is both fields default to required but that requirement clears when the other field is filled out. It fails because webform interprets it as a circular reference.

Any suggestions? I don't have the technical wherewithal to attempt the answer to question [87889](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87889/validate-form-at-least-one-of-the-fields-is-required) so looking for a way to do this using webform conditionals. Question [63912](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63912/how-to-require-one-of-two-fields-to-be-filled-out) looked promising until I realized it dealt with Drupal fields and not Webform fields.

[image: Snippet from webform conditionals]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Webform Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module has what you are looking for (*Require at least one of two fields*).

> The following validation rules are currently included:
>
> - Numeric values (optionally specify min and/or max value)
> - Minimum length
> - Maximum length
> - Minimum number of
>     words
> - Maximum number of words
> - Equal values on
>     multiple fields
> - Unique values on multiple fields
> - Specific value
> - Require at least one of two fields
> - Require at least one of several fields
> - Minimum number of
>     selections required
> - Maximum number of selections allowed
> - Exact number of selections required
> - Plain text (disallow
>     tags)
> - Regular expression
> - Must be empty (anti-spam:
>     Hide with CSS)
> - Words blacklist
> - Must match a
>     username